# Cannot connect to local DynamoDB

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, endpoint, amazon-dynamodb-local

I cannot connect to DynamoDB that is running local using cli.

`aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000`

> > Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "http://localhost:8000/"

This doesn't work either:
`aws dynamodb list-tables --region local`
Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "http://localhost:8000/"

I tried using a different port and that didn't help. I disabled all proxies too.
I am able to connect to DynamoDB using an application like this so I know it's not a dynamodb issue:
`aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://dynamodb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com --region us-west-2`

> > {
> > "TableNames": [
> > "Music"
> > ]
> > }

Comment: How are you starting up the DynamoDb running locally?

Comment: I followed the instructions here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.DownloadingAndRunning.html.    I aso get this in my logs: Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-osx-x86_64 in java.library.path: [.]

Comment: which java version are you using ?

Comment: java version "14.0.1" 2020-04-14

Comment: Actually "Could not connect to the endpoint URL" may happen in various cases, even if no service is listening on host:port (e.g. dynamodb not running or running on different port), so definitely need to run with `aws dynamodb` with `--debug` to see the actual error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in your logs is the key here  `Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-osx-x86_64 in java.library.path: [.]`

This means that the specific dependency cannot be located.

The [link](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-dynamodb-examples/issues/22) that Saranjeet provided has a few solutions. I prefer this solution for testing:

```
First, you need to download the zip file from offcial website. Unzip the file, copy all the *.dll, *.dylib, *.so to a folder under your project root. Say, src/test/resources/libs.
Then, add the code

System.setProperty("sqlite4java.library.path", "src/test/resources/libs/");
before you initialize a local instance of AmazonDynamoDB.
```

Answer (score 3):

When you run

> java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb

command from your terminal make sure output will be like below and no service will be running on port 8000:

```
Initializing DynamoDB Local with the following configuration:
Port:   8000
InMemory:       false
DbPath: null
SharedDb:       true
shouldDelayTransientStatuses:   false
CorsParams:     *
```

It means, this service running successfully on port 8000.

DynamoDB requires **any/fake** credentials to work.

```
AWS Access Key ID: "fakeMyKeyId"
AWS Secret Access Key: "fakeSecretAccessKey"
```

then try below command to list tables.

```
aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

Comment: The output after running java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb is just like above. I have configured my credentials using cli configure and provided the key and secret key. Running aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000 fails

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-osx-x86_64 in java.library.path: [./DynamoDBLocal_lib]

Comment: have a look here: https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-dynamodb-examples/issues/22